# replacement for return inside a generator

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to deploy a Scrapy spider to scraping,however, I wrote code in Python3 which `shub` doesn't allow, so I need to convert code to Python2.7

```
Deploy log last 30 lines:
    _get_apisettings, commands_module='sh_scrapy.commands')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 148, in _run_usercode
    _run(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
    _run_scrapy(args, settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
    execute(settings=settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 338, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/niceprice/spiders/example.py", line 114
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
{"message": "shub-image-info exit code: 1", "details": null, "error": "image_info_error"}
```

it is because of this line in spider

```
    def prase_item(self,response):
        if search('&WS=\d*',response.request.url):
            return 0
```

Is there an equivalent way in achieving this,I tried yielding `None` but it break my pipelines.
I used `return` because I don't want anything to be yielded (stop this iteration from continuing)

Comment: You cannot return a value in Python 2 generators, just use `return`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wrote script using 3.7.3, but shub is forcing me to transfer to code to 2.7

Comment: Why were you returning 0 to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't want to generate or continue with th rest of functions

Comment: I'm asking why `0`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga return 0, basically ends this iteration of spider. and gives nothing to the Pipeline

Comment: so you you *use 0 for no reason?* Why not 1, or 13, or 42? Why 0?